# Any way to have MSP430 wake from sleep and immediately start executing the next instruction after the sleep, avoiding calling into the ISR?

Tags: low-power, interrupts, msp430

I am executing a simple state machine that steps based on a pin change and sleeps between steps. A significant amount of time is spent in the overhead overhead of calling the ISR on each pin change, which increases latency and power consumption. It would be more efficient if I could just have each state update followed by a sleep and then then the next update and sleep, etc.

A very simple example that toggles one of the first for bits of P1 in sequence each time a change happens on a monitored pin.

```
while (1)  {

    P1OUT ^= BIT1;
    __bis_SR_register(LPM4bits+GIE)

    P1OUT ^= BIT2;
    __bis_SR_register(LPM4bits+GIE)

    P1OUT ^= BIT3;
    __bis_SR_register(LPM4bits+GIE)

    P1OUT ^= BIT4;
    __bis_SR_register(LPM4bits+GIE)

}
```

Using an empty ISR with just RETI adds more than 12 extra cycles to each update...

- 6 cycles to enter the ISR (PUSH PC and SR)
- 1 cycle to update the SR so we do not go back to sleep on RETI
- 5 cycles to exit (RETI)

Is there any way to suppress the ISR call on wake on these parts? Seems like there should a be a bit called "do not PUSH PC, load PC from vector, and then JUMP on wake - just PUSH SR and clear GIE and continue execution from PC".

I've tried doing a `__bis_SR_register(LPM4bits+GIE)` at the end of the ISR and then periodically cleaning up the stack, but this still wastes the 6 cycles on the ISR entry which are more important because they increase the latency for updating the output pins.

Maybe some other trick? Would be worth it to lower power consumption and latency by more than 50%.

Thanks!

Comment: I have little experience with msp430, so my comments are general. Just about any micro I’ve come across uses interrupts as the wake mechanism which in terms of design makes perfect sense. The only left field suggestion I have is to add hardware logic to gate the external clock.

Comment: Can you explain your application in more detail? It's difficult to understand why there's enough time between "steps" to make it worthwhile to sleep, yet the dozen or so clocks of latency introduced by the wakeup process is too much. If your power budget is that tight and the processing at each step is so simple, it sounds like you should be using dedicated CMOS logic, not an MCU at all.

Comment: @Kartman On mid-range PICs (eg PIC16F15213), "Wake-up will occur regardless of
the state of the GIE bit. If the GIE bit is disabled, the device continues execution at the instruction after the SLEEP instruction." [DS40002195B-page 96] I do not see anything like this specifically documented on the MSP430, but it seems like there might be a way to do it, especially considering that interrupt sources can wake from the LPMx.5 modes without setting any of the interrupt flags or calling any ISRs.

Comment: @DaveTweed I don't think that time between steps needs to be related to latency sensitivity. To take an extreme example, an airbag may only trigger once every 20 years, but still has a latency deadline on the order of 10's of milliseconds. The beauty of an MCU is that even if _most_ steps are very simple - not all steps need be (above code is a very simplified example). so CMOS would not be practical or cost effective. Power usage is dominated by the frequent simple steps, and the shorter the _average_ step, the more the ISR overhead dominates the time spent (and power wasted) in AM.

Comment: @bigjosh It's been a few years since I last did any MSP430 programming. But I seem to recall that you cannot avoid the interrupt upon wakeup. It's built into the fabric. And if you use the 4.5 version (for those providing it) I think you are forced into accepting a BOR event. As you indicate, it's still worse as the clocks have to fire up. The MSP430 has some of the fastest-starting clocks. But it's not zero, either.